# AWS CLI not working with cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-cli

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
SHELL=/bin/bash

# Create EBS Data snapshot
/usr/local/bin/aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id "vol-XXXXX" --description "test"
```

It works perfectly if I run it from the shell, but does nothing with Cron. Why? I am using IAM roles, is it important?

Comment: I would suggest to use aws-apitools-ec2. it can be install by 
yum install -y aws-apitools-ec2
Here is the reference guide.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ec2-clt.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after several hours I found the solution:

The user root was running the script but AWS was not configured for this user. I only needed to configure AWS for the user root:

```
# aws configure
```

Answer (score 17):

Running `aws configure` as the root user didn't help me, as I had already configured the credentials, and the script ran quite happily for the root user directly from the command line, but would still not run through cron.
The error message I was receiving was;

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

What helped me was adding the following lines to the top of my crontab file, so that the environment was in place for all scripts that ran through cron.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I've been digging google with this issue for a few hours, running AWS commands from a script with crontab should be more easy. nothing seemed to work.

**My Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
backup_date=$(date +%y-%m-%d)
zip /opt/file.zip /opt/file.db
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***********************
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=****************************************
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp /opt/file.zip s3://bucket/backup/$backup_date.file.zip
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp /opt/file.zip s3://bucket/backup/file.zip
rm -f /opt/file.zip
```

**Things that didn't work:**

Define creds in: **aws configure**

Put full path of script into crontab: **0 22 * * * /opt/foo.sh &>> /tmp/foo.log**

Playing around with: **which aws**

**Answer:**

I came across this answer, just put it in the crontab -e:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/env bash /opt/foo.sh &>> /tmp/foo.log
```

Answer (score 2):

you can define credentials directly in your script by defining environment variables:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Answer (score 0):

You should run the aws configure task as root before

```
# aws configure
```

If you're running crontab as root, check also the HOME directory... Change it to

```
HOME=/root
```

at the beginning of /etc/crontab or copy /root/.aws to /.

Answer (score 0):

When using AWS role on EC2 instance (Ubuntu 20.04) `aws ...` is running out of the box when deployed manually (with no need for aws configure) but unsuccessful as cron script.
What was missing, is a path, this does a trick:

```
/usr/local/bin/aws --version
```